# Multiple Interaction in a single test script result into summing up the actions

Tags: c#, selenium, interaction

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Basics._03_Basic_Function
{
    class Slider
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test_Slider()
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://jqueryui.com/slider/");

            IWebElement slderFrame = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@class='demo-frame']"));

            driver.SwitchTo().Frame(slderFrame);

            Thread.Sleep(2500);

            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            
            // Offset 1 to Move Slider by 30 
            IWebElement slider = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='slider']/span[1]"));
            action.DragAndDropToOffset(slider, 30, 0).Build().Perform();
            Thread.Sleep(2500);

            // Offset 2 to Move Slider by 30
            action.DragAndDropToOffset(slider, 30, 0).Build().Perform();
            Thread.Sleep(2500);

            // Offset 3 to Move Slider by 30
            action.DragAndDropToOffset(slider, 30, 0).Build().Perform();
            Thread.Sleep(2500);

            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Problem : There are three interactions in the above test script

**Offset 1** -> *Moves the slider once by 30 *

**Offset 2** -> *Moves the slider twice by 30 each (total move by 60)*

**Offset 3** -> *Moves the slider thrice by 30 each (total move by 90)*

why these actions are summing up ??
How can it be protected to summing up ??

Comment: maybe try getting the slider element before each action.

Comment: @pcalkins : Thanks for the hint, But it is not working. :)

But after Release the action working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code working fine. Release the action after each perform

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Basics._03_Basic_Function
{
    [Category("03 Basic Function")]
    class SliderTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test_Slider()
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://jqueryui.com/slider/");

            IWebElement slderFrame = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@class='demo-frame']"));

            driver.SwitchTo().Frame(slderFrame);

            Thread.Sleep(2500);

            Actions action = new Actions(driver);

            // Offset 1 to Move Slider by 30 
            IWebElement slider = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='slider']/span[1]"));
            action.DragAndDropToOffset(slider, 30, 0).Perform();
            action.Release();
            Thread.Sleep(2500);

            // Offset 2 to Move Slider by 30 
            action = new Actions(driver);
            action.DragAndDropToOffset(slider, 30, 0).Perform();
            action.Release();
            Thread.Sleep(2500);

            // Offset 3 to Move Slider by 30 
            action = new Actions(driver);
            action.DragAndDropToOffset(slider, 30, 0).Perform();
            Thread.Sleep(2500);

            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: creating `Actions` class object without reference object:

```
IWebElement slider = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='slider']/span[1]"));

// Offset 1 to Move Slider by 30 
new Actions(driver).DragAndDropToOffset(slider, sliderOffsetX, 0).Perform();
Thread.Sleep(1000);

// Offset 2 to Move Slider by 30 
new Actions(driver).DragAndDropToOffset(slider, sliderOffsetX, 0).Perform();
Thread.Sleep(1000);

// Offset 3 to Move Slider by 30
new Actions(driver).DragAndDropToOffset(slider, sliderOffsetX, 0).Perform();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```